# How to make a client-side fingerprint javascript

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, scripting, fingerprint

I want to make a client-side fingerprint using javascript to avoid registrations of users.

How can I make it? I would like to send it to the server with the post request.

I want to send a get request with the fingerprint to the server and then redirect on the normal site.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can say you it's a very bad idea. I'm not sure what your site is for, but client side fingerprinting is not enough to authenticate anyone.

Comment: I'd say read [ask] and do a search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=client-side+fingerprint

Comment: The site will show pictures to the user. One picture will be shown only once on every page loading.

Comment: And why do you need to register? If you use fingerprinting, it's likely that someone will get access to someone else's account, and that you can't log into the same account from any other device. Many people have already blocked most means to create client fingerprints, because they can be used to track you without using cookies.

Comment: I do not want to register users

Comment: I get that, but why would you need to? Just use sessionstorage to store some kind of session id, no need for fingerprinting, the session id can be random.

Comment: I recommend researching a little more before coming to the stack community.   They can be kinda harsh sometimes.   Particularly look at node/passport or google/firebase/apps

Comment: Check if this helps you : http://camsunit.com/application/html-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html. It supports the javascript sdk to integrate with biomeric system